# Centering a Sortable Row Header in the GridView

Tags: asp.net, html, css, gridview

I cannot seem to center the header text of a column in my GridView if it is sortable. The html output is much different for a sortable column (it seems to place a table inside of the td column).

Any thoughts on what can be done to get this centered?
I put the html ouput in a jsfiddle here ... http://jsfiddle.net/mcox05/85Euq/

I have tried the following code on the grid view with no success. Bear in mind that the bound fields are server controls I designed but they do not affect the header text in any fashion:
I am open to any css, js, or asp.net fix that can correct this issue. Thanks!

```
 <sc:DateBoundField DataField="LastLogin" SortExpression="LastLogin" HeaderText="Last Login"
                    HeaderStyle-Width="125px" ItemStyle-Width="125px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <sc:SCommandButtonField Command="Change" ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                    HeaderText="Change" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Image="img.axd?ico16=edit" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the style of your inner table to look like `style="height: 32px; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; margin:auto;"` it will center, at least in FF.

Comment: thank you for your help. I posted on how I implemented your solution.